# Godot 4.1 How to detect what tile did rigidbody2d collide with?

Tags: c#, godot4

I have a special tile in the tilemap, that when colliding with player needs to do a special behviour. Since i cant add anything specila to the tile, the logic needs to be set up on the player side. But i cant seem to figure out how to find what tile the player is colliding with. All existing tutorials are for Godot 3.x where Tilemap collision system is different than in 4.1.

Does anybody know how to get the tile player is colliding with in godot 4.1? Also im using C# as the scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisites**:
I assume you work in 2D and have Sprite2D colliding with a tile in TileMap.

**The short answer is**:

Use `Area2D` as phisics body and subscribe to `body_entered` signal, it receives colliding object as an argument.

**The long answer is**:

To make collision happen and be able to detect with which object you've collided you need to add `Area2D` node to your `Sprite2D` and add shape (object inherits from `Shape2D`) as child to `Area2D`.
Now you need to add colliders to your tiles, first select `TileMap`, and click "add physics layer" (it was something like that) in Inspector. Then, in bottom tab, select `TileSet`, select a tile and you'll see that physics layer properties are now added. You will need to draw or select all of it.

[Here is an image that might clarify the `TileSet` part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnE2O.png)

Soooo, now you have colliders in place. All you need to do now is to subscribe to 'body_entered' signal of `Area2D` node, and you'll get the colliding object as an argument to the handler.